# How does the region $(1-x)^2+y^2 \leq K \left (1 - \sqrt {x^2 + y^2} \right )$ look like?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

> How does the region $(1-x)^2+y^2 \leq K \left (1 - \sqrt {x^2 + y^2} \right )$ look like?

I drew few demo regions in desmos for different values of $K$ and every time it seems like that the region is bounded by a circle contained in the unit disk except for $K = 1$ which gives rise to a region bounded by a balloon like shape. Does the equation $(1-x)^2+y^2 = K \left (1 - \sqrt {x^2 + y^2} \right )$ represent a circle for $K \neq 1\ $? I am very curious to know that.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried values close to but not equal to $1$?

Comment: @TravisWillse$:$ I haven't tried that. Will that help anyway to conclude whether the required curve is a circle or not? I didn't get your hint probably. Sorry for that.

Comment: @TravisWillse$:$ I just find another way to view this region which is the following $:$ $$\bigcup\limits_{0 \leq r \leq K} (A_r \cap B_r),$$ where $$A_r : = \left \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2\ |\ (x-1)^2+y^2 \leq r^2 \right \}$$ and, $$B_r : = \left \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2\ |\ x^2 + y^2 = \left (1 - \frac r K \right )^2 \right \}.$$ Don't know whether it will help or not. The point $(1,0)$ can be obtained by putting $r = 0.$

Comment: The curve is visibly not a circle for, say, $K = \frac{11}{10}$.

Comment: @TravisWillse$:$ I think any value of $K$ closer to $1$ could potentially gives rise to a region bounded by a curve which does not resemble to that of a circle. Is there any specific reason for that? I am still unable to find it out. This question is motivated from the regions on the complex plane known as non-tangential approach region with centre at $1.$ This plays a pivotal role in the study of analytic function spaces i.e. the Hardy spaces for instance.

Comment: Put another way, we can ask why the boundary is approximately circular for $K$ far from $1$: If $K$ is large, then dividing by $K$ gives that the boundary of the region satisfies $0 \approx 1 - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, the unit circle. If $K$ is small, expanding in a power series gives that the boundary satisfies $\left[x - \left(1 - \frac{K}2\right)\right]^2 + y^2 \approx \frac{K^2}{4}$, i.e., a circle of radius $\frac{K}2$ centered at $\left(1 - \frac{K}2, 0\right)$.

Comment: @TravisWillse$:$ Could you please explain the last part of your comment when $K$ is small? What is the power series you are talking about which needs to be expanded? Is it $(1-K)^{-1}\ $?

Comment: Expand $F_K(x, y) := (1 - x)^2 + y^2 - K \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}$ in a series about $x = 1 - \frac{K}2, y = 0, K = 0$.

Comment: @TravisWillse$:$ Where do you get the term $\sqrt {1 - x^2 - y^2}\ $?

Comment: @TravisWillse$:$ Don't know how did you expand it. Taylor's expansion about $x,y,K$ where $x$ is itself depending over $K.$ What an idea sir! :)

Answer (score 0):

We may as well ask about the boundary of the region, namely, the curve $C_K$ defined by
$$(1 - x)^2 + y^2) = K \left(1 - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right) .$$ The following plot shows $C_K$ for various values of $K$ along with the limiting circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.
[image]

As is apparent from some of the curves, no, the boundary is not a circle: Rearranging the equation gives that $C_K$ is some subset of the quartic algebraic curve
$$F_K(x, y) := [(x - 1)^2 + y^2 - K]^2 - K^2 (x^2 + y^2) = 0,$$
and for generic values of $K$ it has genus $1$---hence it does not even have a rational parameterization---whereas a circle has genus $0$.

In at least 2 cases $C_K$ has genus $0$ but neither case is a circle:

- $K = 0$: the (real) locus $C_0$ is a single point, $(1, 0)$, and
- $K = 1$: the locus $C_1$ is an arc of the limaçon $r = 1 + 2 \cos \theta$.

One the other hand, for $K \ll 1$ and $K \gg 1$ the curve is approximately a circle, and some algebra suggests why.

Rearranging gives
$$1 - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \frac{(x - 1)^2 + y^2}{K} .$$ The right-hand side is positive, so $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$, hence the left-hand side is $\leq \frac{4}{K}$, so for $K \gg 1$ we have $1 - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \approx 0$, and $1 - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ defines the unit circle.

For $K \ll 1$, changing coordinates to $(u, y)$, $x = u + \left(1 - \frac{K}2\right)$, and forming the power series at $u = y = K = 0$ gives that
$$0 = u^2 + y^2 - \frac{K^2}{4} + E,$$
where $E$ is an error whose terms have total degree at least $3$ in $u, y, K$, so that $u^2 + y^2 \approx \left(\frac{K}2\right)^2$, and $u^2 + y^2 = \left(\frac{K}2\right)^2$ defines the circle of radius $\frac{K}2$ centered at $(u, y) = (0, 0)$, i.e., at $(x, y) = \left(1 - \frac{K}2, 0\right)$.

**Remark** The original curve has a compact polar representation:

$$r^2 + (K - 2 \cos \theta) r + (1 - K) = 0$$